# Склонение фамилии мужчины Патана

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Можно ли склонять фамилию мужчины Патана, уроженца Украины?

Answer (score 1):

Подобные фамилии славянского происхождения, как правило, склоняются. Если же фамилия иностранная, то - нет. Лучше всего было бы уточнить у владельца, но если такой возможности нет, то я бы предпочёл б не склонять.